# Session timeout Test Katalon/Selenium

Tags: selenium, session, timeout, katalon-studio

I have to test a website, to see if it logs out the user after 2 hours of inactivity, but I do not want to wait 2 hours for the test to finish. Is there a way to test the session timeout of a website faster with Katalon or Selenium?

Comment: Session Timeout doesn't depends On Selenium. You should contact website developers if there is a way to reduce session timeout using any config entries or by other means?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... But suppose the dev doesn't change the session timeout, then the only way is to test it for 2 hours?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes!